# Running two geth instance on same pc

Tags: go-ethereum

I wanted to run two geth instance simultaneously using

```
First console
geth --ws --ws.origins http://localhost:3000 --ws.port 8545 --ws.api eth,net,web3,personal --datadir="F:\EthereumMainNet`

Second console
geth --ws --ws.port 8546 --ws.api eth,net,web3,personal --datadir="F:\EthereumMainNet
```

and I get error about the folder being in used. Is it possible to run multiple instance sharing same `--datadir`? or do I need to duplicated the `EthereumMainNet` on different folder to be able to use by other?

Comment: Each geth instance needs its own data directory. Also need to use separate p2p port (`--port <P2P_PORT>`) and different ipc paths (or disable ipc in one of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mast to create 2 different instances of the folder EthereumMainNet

Comment: does it need to have both contain the whole sync data?